# anchor ng-click calling 2 methods

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs

We are using angular to do like/unlike behavior for our app.

Code for html

```html
<html>
  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="newsCntrl" >
      <form ng-submit="post()" name="postForm" id="postForm" >
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/>
      </form> 
      <a href="#" ng-click="likePost(post.id);">Like</a></span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Code for controller

```
myApp.controller("newsFeedCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {       
   console.log("inside newsFeedCtrl"); 

  $scope.post() = function() {  
    console.log("posting");
  }
  $scope.likePost = function(postId) { 
    console.log("liking post");
  }

});
```

The problem is when we click on like; it also calls post function which should not be happening.

Are we missing anything here?

Comment: Can you show your HTML?

Comment: remove the () from the post method: `$scope.post = function()` not `$scope.post() = function()`

Comment: Ahh thanks for pointing out; but that is not helping :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a mismatch between the controller name in the HTML:

```
  <div ng-controller="newsCntrl" >
```

and the controller in the JS:

```
  myApp.controller("newsFeedCtrl", function ($scope, $http)
```

If I fix it, it seems to work. 
Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nJr9L/)

Comment: @ronen..Thanks for pointing out..but sadly that didnt helped.  Actually now i was able to resolve this issue.  I changed my href="#" to ng-href=""

Answer (score 1):

You should remove syntax error

Code for html:

```html
<html> 
  <body ng-app="myApp"> 
    <div ng-controller="newsCntrl"> 
     <form ng-submit="submitPost()" name="postForm" id="postForm"> 
       <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/> 
     </form> 
     <a href="#" ng-click="likePost(post.id);">Like</a> 
    </div> 
 </body> 
</html>
```

Code for controller:

```js
myApp.controller("newsFeedCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {       
  console.log("inside newsFeedCtrl"); 

  $scope.submitPost = function() {  
    console.log("posting");
  }

  $scope.likePost = function(postId) { 
    console.log("liking post");
  }    
});
```

Comment: If you want a post use a different name